# Load data in advance on Website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a script on a page that will set diffrent src on a img element, the problem is that when the src is set it will take some time for the browser to fetch the image.

Is it possible to load this at formload instead? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at jquery's method [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) also [here](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript) is a useful link

Comment: Your link solved my problem, I did however not see that the solution uses .load. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```

and while the images are loading you can probably include a loading spinner to them and remove them once load is done

Answer (score 2):

You could also load all of the images on the page as hidden using "display:none" as the style.

```
<img id="pic1" src="pic1.jpg" style="display:none" />  
<img id="pic2" src="pic2.jpg" style="display:none" />
```

Then use something like jquery's show() and hide() methods to show the image element that you need.

```
$("#pic1").show();
```